# WCF maxReceivedMessageSize not working over HTTPS

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, https, maxreceivedmessagesize

I'm trying to receive large XML messages using a WCF service encriptes with SSL over HTTPS. My application is built over .NET Framework 4.5 and is deployed on a IIS 8.5 server.

Using the following Web.Config configuration I'm able to receive the large XML over HTTP but it presents some problems over HTTPS. (HTTPS communications is already working fine, with a self signed certificate and all).

```
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <basicHttpsBinding>
         <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880"/>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>   
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
```

PErforming some tests using SoapUI, the large file is only sent over HTTPS when the definitions are updated (even without any changes in the Web.Config file).

When an external system (TIBO/PI from SAP) calls our service it simplr doesen't work, presenting the following error message:

HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large 
Cache-Control: private 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVkFMRVxDb2RpZ28tYnJhbmNoLW9uZGExLW9uZGEyLW1lcmdlXFN1cHBsaWVyRmluYW‌​5jZS5XZWJTZXJ2aWNlc1xDb250cmF0b3Muc3Zj?= 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 22:28:41 GMT Content-Length: 0

Comment: Can you show config for client proxy and endpoints?

Comment: So far I'm testing using SoapUI (with no sucess, but, also, no special configuration) and without explicit endpoins on the Web.config (so, all endpoints use the same configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this binding (I explicitly specified the name of binding so use it in service configuration)

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
```

If it does not work try to add

```
<system.webServer>
    <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483646"/>
</system.webServer>
```

to you configuration. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you only have a configuration for basicHttpBinding but not for basicHttpsBinding. Create the default configuration for the SSL-based binding as well:

```
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" maxBufferSize="5242880"/>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: I've applied this aditional tags on my Web.config. However, the solution appears to be unstable, working in a moment and thaen, stop working again. Do you imagine what can be causing this?

Comment: When it "doesn't work" how does it behave? Error? if so, which one?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVkFMRVxDb2RpZ28tYnJhbmNoLW9uZGExLW9uZGEyLW1lcmdlXFN1cHBsaWVyRmluYW5jZS5XZWJTZXJ2aWNlc1xDb250cmF0b3Muc3Zj?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2015 22:28:41 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Comment: You could certainly be going over the configured limit. Have you tried increasing it?

Comment: The configured limit is a business requirement, but, we're testing it with a controled, lower size. All the tests work just fine with HTTP, but some tests  are intermitent with HTTPS (as I said, sometimes they work and sometimes they don't). 
The problem occurs at our local machine and in the DEV machine as well.

Comment: The problem is that you're assuming that messages are exactly the same size when SSL is involved, which might not be the case. Try increasing the limit a bit and see if the error still comes up with your test message sizes.

Comment: We've set the limit to 10MB. The problem occurs when sending messages with 80KB or higher.